# npm init results in package manager console stuck with "Press ^C at any time to quit."

Tags: vue.js, npm, visual-studio-2019

When I try to type "npm init" in the package console manager it starts the process, but the console is stuck with the message: "Press ^C at any time to quit.". I can create my package.json file, and I am therefore completely stuck. When running the whole program I get the error: "The command "npm run build" exited with code 1.".

Error when running "npm init":

[image]

I know a lot of people had success with removing the package_lock.json filer and node_modules folder, but this solves nothing for me. Stuck for 10 hours now - can anyone help?

Comment: Try installing another new version of nodejs using something like NVM and then use that other version